# After uploading Laravel 6.0 project I am getting "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." error

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-6

The project is working on my local server without error. But after uploading the project to the server I am getting

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

error. I used Laravel 6.0

Api.php:

```
Route::post('rates', 'ShippoController@rates');
```

Controller:

```
public function rates(Request $request){
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'name' => 'required',
        'token' => 'required',
    ]);

    try{

        $carts = Cart::whereToken($request->token)->get();
        if (count($carts) == 0){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 0,
                'message' => 'Invalid cart token.',
            ], Response::HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
        }

        ...

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 1,
            'data' => $data,
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e){
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ], Response::HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY);
    }
}
```

[image: It is a screenshot while working on my local server:]

[image: It is the error after uploading to the server]

Comment: It's probably an issue with your web server configuration, which turns the POST request into a GET request instead.

Comment: It was working yesterday on server

Comment: But I got this error after updating my composer. I added to composer: `"symfony/translation": "4.3.8"`

Comment: why did you add that directly to your composer.json? i get the feeling you are ending up in a situation where you have 2 different php versions in play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that http://canvas.safedevs.com/ redirects to [http**s**://canvas.safedevs.com/](http://canvas.safedevs.com/). When a redirect occurs, the POST is converted to a GET and the post data lost.

Send the request to the HTTPS version of the endpoint and it should work fine.

Insomnia [apparently has a feature to disable automatically following redirects](https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/pull/1737), which you might consider turning on. It'll give you better visibility on issues like this.

Comment: Thank you very much @ceejayoz for your help. It works.