# The GET method is not supported for this route (problem with redirection on laravel )

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error on my laravel project. It works on my local server but not when deploying with laravel forge...

```
<form action="{{ route('accept-channel', $el->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
   ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

```
public function accept(Request $req, $id){
     dd($req);
}
```

```
Route::post('/admin/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ChannelController@accept')->name('accept-channel');
```

I also have a "Reject" button and everything works fine (I don't understand why...) :

```
<a href="{{ route('reject-channel', $el->id) }}">Rejeter</a>
```

```
public function reject($id){
    Channel::find($id)->delete();
    return redirect()->route('admin');
}
```

```
Route::get('/admin/{id}/reject', 'App\Http\Controllers\ChannelController@reject')->name('reject-channel');
```

I think that I have the same issue [After uploading Laravel 6.0 project I am getting "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430945/after-uploading-laravel-6-0-project-i-am-getting-the-get-method-is-not-supporte), but I don't know how to resolve it...

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that it's not doing a HTTP -> HTTPS redirect anywhere. You can watch the requests in the Network tab of your browser's developer console

Comment: Hello, I'm not finding this information. But it is probably the case. I also found this issue https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1843#issuecomment-580065822. But what to do to use https on requests?

Comment: First, did you check your routes with
artisan route:list
If needed did you clear the route cache ?
artisan cache:clear

Comment: Yes, I checked the routes and cleared cache

Comment: I renamed the route. What's interesting is that I have an other form with same structure and everything works...